# ¿Como agrego una consulta dentro de un CASE en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente `query`:

```
select 
`preguntas`.`tipo`, 
`preguntas`.`puntaje`, 
`preguntas`.`descrip`, 
`preguntas`.`numero`, 
`preguntas`.`v_f`, 
`preguntas`.`seleccion`, 
`preguntas`.`desarrollo`, 
CASE `preguntas`.`tipo` 
WHEN 2 THEN (select * from `preguntas_selecciones` where `preguntas_selecciones`.`preguntas_id`=`preguntas`.`id`) 
ELSE 0 
END as 'respuestas' 
from `preguntas` 
where `preguntas`.`evaluaciones_id` = 6 
order by `preguntas`.`numero` asc;
```

Si coloco como resultado en el `THEN` cualquier valor me da el resultado correctamente, pero si agrego el `query` me arroja el siguiente error:

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

¿Sera que no es posible hacer un consulta dentro de un `CASE`?

Comment: te recomiendo que veas la documentacion de MYSQL aqui te indica las posibilidades que puedes usar en CASE 
 : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El subquery debe devolver una sola columna. El `*` hace que devuelva más de una columna y eso es lo que indica el error. Es lógico que no puedas guardar un conjunto de valores en una sola columna pensada para tener un solo valor.
Debes cambiar el `*` por el nombre de una columna de la tabla `preguntas_selecciones`

Comment: Efectivamente era el problema. Gracias.